# how to use % instead of px to set height in google map?

Tags: html, css

i'm new here and trying to ask how to use percentage instead using px, i'm not sure is that my code problem or anything else, so i just show my code here to check is it whether my code problem or what, i tried use % in my code but doesn't work for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [
    {
        "lat": '3.147746',
        "lng": '101.575272',
        "description": 'Aksa Beach is a popular beach and a vacation spot in Aksa village at Malad, Mumbai.'
    },
    ];
    window.onload = function () {
        LoadMap();
    }
    function LoadMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i];
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,

            });

            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:300px;min-height:10px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
</script>
```

this code is work for me

```
<div id="map" style="height: 550px"> </div>
```

and i tried this code but not work

```
<div id="map" style="height:80%"></div>
```

Comment: The 80% must refer to a parent element. That could be the issue.

Comment: The question is 80% of what - if you check the height of the parent of `#map`, I suspect you'll find it's not the height of the window. Try using `80vh`, which should set it to 80% of the vertical height of the viewport.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with javascript/google api. Show us your html and css (but only the necessary parts).

Comment: thanks Toby, vh is work for me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do one thing. Just give `100%` height to body tag

```
<body style="height:100%;">

</body>
```

Now you can try

`<div id="map" style="height:80%"></div>`

It will work.

Answer (score -2):

It is a CSS limitation. `%` does not work for height.

Instead, try using the well known method for YouTube responsiveness :
Put your content in absolute positioning into a container with a `padding-top:80%`

padding-top/-bottom % are based on the container width.